# Sequel Model set_schema not found

Tags: ruby, sequel

Can any one volunteer why the class below fails?

```
... src/model/user.rb:18: undefined method `set_schema' for User:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I've looked in the Sequel-3.0 lib/ folder and the `set_schema` method is defined in a `ClassMethods` module.

I'm sure the solution is simple.  I was thinking it should work "as is":

```
require 'sequel'

class User < Sequel::Model(:user)

  set_schema do
    set_primary_key :id
    String          :name
  end 
end
```

Comment: Please re-edit your question and add updates to it instead of adding multiple answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommended way ...

```
LOGGER = Object.new()
def LOGGER.method_missing( name, args )
    puts "[#{name}] #{args}"
end

Sequel::Model.plugin(:schema)                       # I worked this out, but I can't find it documented

DB = Sequel.sqlite('sql_test.db', :loggers => [LOGGER] )

unless  DB.table_exists?( :user ) 
    DB.create_table :user  do
        set_primary_key :id
        String          :name
        String          :password
        String          :eMail
    end #create_table
end #table exists
class User < Sequel::Model(:user)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to call up the plug-in for schema managing.  Viz.

```
require 'sequel'
require 'logger'

LOGGER = Object.new()
def LOGGER.method_missing( name, args )
    puts "[#{name}] #{args}"
end

**Sequel::Model.plugin(:schema)**            # I still didn't find this documented

DB = Sequel.sqlite('sql_test.db', :loggers => [LOGGER] )


class User < Sequel::Model(:user)

  set_schema do
    set_primary_key :id
    String          :name
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep `Sequel::Model.plugin(:schema)` worked for me too.  Can't see it in the docs and I'm perplexed as to why, since I have another working project that uses `set_schema` without fuss.

Comment: Hi Joe ... Y

Yes, I looked over the new way Sequel works now, it uses plugins for things like the schema, etc.  On the sequel mailing list they advised me to do it as shown below.

Good luck, w.